# Homestead attempting to re-download box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile, homestead

I manually downloaded laravel homestead box from atlas and the version i downloaded is **0.2.6** of **laravel/homestead**.

Then i git clone `https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`.

After doing the other necessary configurations when i am trying to run vagrant up from Homestead directory, it is starting to download the laravel/homestead box again with version **0.4.0**.

My internet is slow and i cannot afford to download the box again. Is there any way i can tell Homestead to use the existing homestead box already exist in my ~/.vagrant.d directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Locate this `homestead.rb` at your drive, mine is at `C:\Users\SuperComputer\Homestead\scripts\homestead.rb`

Edit it using text editor.

try find this word syntax:

`config.vm.box_version = settings["version"] ||= ">= 0"`

change it to

`config.vm.box_version = settings["version"] ||= "= 0.2.6"`

Comment: Oh i forget to remove > this and it wasn't working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this as shown https://abbasharoon.me/laravel-homestead-windows-extremely-easy/ and here http://laravel.io/forum/05-06-2015-how-to-download-vagrant-box-manually is to add the metadata_url file. Without that file, Vagrant will try to download the homestead even after installing the manually downloaded homestead box. To add the metadata_url, follow the following steps:

1. Download the metadata file from [here](https://abbasharoon.me/metadata_url)
2. Move the metadata_url file to C://Users/YourUserName/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead.
3. In case you have configured a different directory for Vagrant’s
   storage then you will need to find the boxes directory there
   Inside the laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead directory, rename the directory “0” to the current version which is currently 0.5.0